# How do i use the Steam SDK to login?

Tags: c#, winforms, sdk, steam

I wanted to do a program where I can add a few accounts, to login with one click.
I tried to add a dll as reference but that didn't work.
The problem is, I dont know how I use the sdk (folder) that i downloaded, in my C# WinForm project.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the docs at [SteamKit2](https://github.com/SteamRE/SteamKit) are pretty straight forward. I coded a bot for myself and dont know if it works on the latest version of steam client but yeah i have a clear idea about what to do.

If you have a look [here](https://github.com/rishav394/Steam-bot/blob/master/Steam/Program.cs) you create a new steamClient and subscribe to events.

```
_steamClient = new SteamClient();
```

and then connect to the client.

```
            _manager = new CallbackManager(_steamClient);
            _steamUser = _steamClient.GetHandler<SteamUser>();
            _steamFriends = _steamClient.GetHandler<SteamFriends>();
            _manager.Subscribe<SteamClient.ConnectedCallback>(OnConnected);
            _manager.Subscribe<SteamClient.DisconnectedCallback>(OnDisconnected);
            _manager.Subscribe<SteamUser.LoggedOnCallback>(OnLoggedOn);
            _manager.Subscribe<SteamUser.LoggedOffCallback>(OnLoggedOff);
            _manager.Subscribe<SteamUser.AccountInfoCallback>(OnAccountInfo);
            _manager.Subscribe<SteamUser.UpdateMachineAuthCallback>(OnMachineAuth);
            _manager.Subscribe<SteamFriends.FriendMsgCallback>(OnChatMessage);
            _manager.Subscribe<SteamFriends.FriendsListCallback>(OnFriendList);
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to steam in 3s");
            _steamClient.Connect();
```